# show document lib. action for custom type only for particular site specific site alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I need to show doc lib action for specific type (qwe:customtype). change to be reflected at particular site and non site areas(Myfiles/Repository) only.

**alfrescoShare-slingshot-application-context.xml**

```
<bean id="for-specifictype-only" parent="evaluator.doclib.action.nodeType">
<property name="types">

  <list>
            <value>qwe:customtype</value>
        </list>

</property>
</bean>
```

**share-config-custom.xml**

```
<action id="document-assign-workflow" type="javascript" label="actions.document.assign-workflow">
                <param name="function">onActionAssignWorkflow</param>
               <evaluator>for-specifictype-only</evaluator>
 </action>
```

ForEx::   Only  nodes of type qwe:customtype at "abc" site should be able to view doc lib action.

For other sites,it should be visible to all types of nodes.( like cm:folder type node at other site should be able to view this action)
Do we need a any custom site evaluater here?As there is no default eveluater which takes specific site name as parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is doable with a little work. First, go look at the ChainedMatchAll evaluator (evaluator.doclib.action.chainedMatchAll). You can find it in slingshot-documentlibrary-context.xml.

You can create your own evaluator that has it as a parent, and then list all of the evaluators that need to be true in order for the chained evaluator to be true. There are several examples in slingshot-documentlibrary-context.xml--a simple one is evaluator.doclib.metadata.hasSyncFailedBanner.

In your case, you'll use the nodeType evaluator, which you've already discovered, and a custom site evaluator which you'll have to write.

To develop an evaluator that can be used to match on a specific site, first go take a look at [this tutorial](http://docs.alfresco.com/community/tasks/dev-extensions-share-tutorials-custom-evaluator.html) from the Alfresco docs. It covers creating custom evaluators.

The site is in the URL so you should be able to parse it using the RequestContext which is passed to the evaluator's applyModule method.

Using your custom site evaluator, the existing nodeType evaluator, and the chainedMatchAll evaluator, you can then show or hide actions based on the node type and specific site ID.

Comment: solved with share extension modules declaring doc. lib action configuration.